# Page not found when proxying with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx running on a server. It has the default configuration.
So

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  myservername.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://OTHER_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;
    }
```

When I run:

```
curl http://myservername.com
```

I see the default "Welcome to nginx"

When I run

```
curl http://myservername.com/api
or even
http://myservername.com/api/           
or even
http://myservername.com/api/index.html
```

I get a NOT FOUND.

If I go directly to:

```
http://OTHER_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS
```

Then I see the response: "THIS IS THE API"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I needed to do was adding a slash after the ip address:

```
proxy_pass http://OTHER_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/;
```

instead of

```
proxy_pass http://OTHER_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;
```